# Android Download Manager

Tags: android, file, path, filepath, download-manager

I think i have a rather simple question.

http://www.vogella.com/blog/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/

I have been following a tutorial in the above url.

How do I change the filepath for downloads?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You configure the [DownloadManager.Request](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html) object with that sort of information. In the tutorial, that `Request` object is created and used in `onClick()`.

For example:

```
DownloadManager.Request req=new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

req.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                               | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
   .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
   .setTitle("Demo")
   .setDescription("Something useful. No, really.")
   .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
                                      "test.mp4");
```

(above code is from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Internet/Download))

Comment: The last line is the important one :) At first I stumbled a bit on that.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare I am still not certain on how to tell DownloadManager what folder to store the files in :(.

Something like you would do in Async 
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/Myfolder/file_name.extension");

Comment: @Mich: `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir()` and related methods let you specify the output directory as a `File`, not as an `OutputStream`.

Comment: Thanks. Just starting to understand it

Comment: @CommonsWare if I want to change destination to my aplication databases folder. what should I do?  I have tried with this code `.setDestinationUri(dst_uri);` but it gives error **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a file URI:**

Comment: @mehmet: `DownloadManager` cannot write to your app's internal storage (e.g., `getDatabasePath()`). Beyond that, whatever `dst_uri` is does not have the `file://` scheme, apparently.

Comment: @CommonsWare I found this solution what u think. `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(dst_uri.getPath()).mkdirs();` `request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(dst_uri.getPath(), "file name with . ext" );`

Comment: @mehmet: `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` does not take a path as a parameter.

Answer (score 5):

The last line in CommonsWare's answer states the destination. He just uses the regular download-folder on the sdcard, but you could as well do this:

```
req.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/mnt/sdcard/Myfolder", "file_name.extension");
```

Comment: What is the downside of using req.setDestinationUri(uri) or
req.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir

Comment: You could also use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` instead of hardcoding to **"/mnt/sdcard"**

Answer (score 2):

You make sure external storage access is permitted by user for your app. Include this code for the download

```
DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
     Uri uri = Uri.parse(url_string);
     DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);        
     request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    // include this line if permission has been granted by user to external directory
     request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, uri.getLastPathSegment());  
// or this line if not yet granted
request.setDestinationUri(Uri.parse("file://" + uri.getLastPathSegment());      
    Long reference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do following:

1. Visit the URL to understand about Download Manager https://github.com/quoraboy/DownloadManagerInAndroid
2. As far as I understand you can't pause/resume download manually.
3. If you cancel the download then it totally depends on your server whether they support pause/resume feature or not. If yes then, after cancelling the download, if you start the download again it may actually resume it and don't start downloading from beginning.

Comment: One can `pause` and `resume` the download in `download manager`