# Secure downloaded Files in android applications with internal storage and encrypting usage?

Tags: android, encryption, android-contentprovider, internal-storage

I am working on an Android application which downloads files in External storage.

I want to download them in internal storage and encrypt them so they become secure even with a rooted device.
I found that we can work with internal storage and encrypting the files and to use them with external intents we use content-provider.

Dose some one worked with this kind of stuff ? (internal-storage + encrypting + decrypting + content-providers).

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the download manager to download files using async task.
After that encrypt and decrypt that files.
please refer [How to encrypt file from SD card using AES in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782187/how-to-encrypt-file-from-sd-card-using-aes-in-android)

Comment: is there a possibility to use internal storage with DownloadManager?

Comment: Yes you can use download manager to download files from server.There lot of samples available.
check this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906725/android-download-manager
If you are looking for frame work kind of thing check this.
https://github.com/smanikandan14/ThinDownloadManager

Comment: This is entirely inappropriate - you are proposing to download the file to the world-readable external storage, and only then encrypt it.